# Parse PHP text file into multiple variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a TXT file that contains different kind of configuration (Routers configuration), for example like this:

```
    Router model C1i IPSec CR 1 95 CPU MPC860      S/N: 444/33333
    1 LAN, 1 ISDN Line, 1 XDSL Line
    CIT software version: 10.4.2.0.3 Oct 22 2004 10:24:51


    Router *
    Router *p 3
    Console Operator
    Router +net atm

    -- ATM Console --
    Router atm0/0 monitor+list all

    Description: ADSL over POTS (Alcatel DynaMiTe P) over Motorola MPC860 SAR

    ---- Status ----
    Transmission:       ENABLED     Phy rate:        320 kbps
    Reception:          ENABLED     Phy rate:       3008 kbps
    Status:                  UP     for       0/04:10:54 (days/hh:mm:ss)

    ---- Statistics ----
    Tx user cells        =     308481         Rx user cells        =    5059007
    Tx no user cells     =          0         Rx no  user cells    =          0
                                              Rx invalid           =          0
                                              Rx missinserted      =          0
                                              Rx future functions  =          0
    Tx bytes             =   16349493         Rx bytes             =  268127371
    Tx last 5 min (kbps) =          0         Rx last 5 min (kbps) =          0

    Linked structs       =        100 (10 free)
```

I want to parse from PHP, detecting interesting info, like Serial Number, disposition of ports, ATM speed, etc.

The problem is that I don't know how detect the different words, for example S/N, "Transmission", "Reception", "Status". There is a function called strpos, but it is only for one term, not for various.

```
    <?php


    if ($gestor = (@fopen("documento.txt", "r")))
            {
            while (($bufer = fgets($gestor, 4096)) !== FALSE) 
                {
                switch ($bufer)
                    {
                    case "Router Model":
                    echo"DETECTADO";
                    break;
                    default:
                    echo $bufer;
                    break;
                    }

                echo "<br />";
                }
            if (!feof($gestor)) {
                echo "Error: fallo inesperado de fgets()\n";
            }
            fclose($gestor);
            }
        else
            {
        echo "Error al abrir el fichero";

            }

    ?>
```

The last option I have is parsing the entire TXT file for each variable I want to store, but is not efficient.

Thank you.

Comment: You're basically trying to build a Parser. That's a fairly complex bit of code.

Comment: Its also user information, therefore not machine readable or necessarily backwards compatible.

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions (RegEx) and PHP's `preg` functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day your going to need a parser.

my recommendation is something like this:

Find all the words in the text file that has a ":" at the end of it. (Being the important so called headers for interesting data) Once you do that find the value to the right of it minus any spaces and you have your value to store.

Comment: Well, that's true. Finally I used other way to parse the file without PHP. Thank you